# kivy windows app is not launching

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, pyinstaller

I have the following project structure:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOlSZ.png)

and am trying to generate .exe application through Pyinstaller tutorial [here](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html)
I have got the following .spec file:

```
   # -*- mode: python -*-
    from kivy.deps import glew



    block_cipher = None


    a =       Analysis(['C:\\Users\\Mohamad\\PycharmProjects\\offline_file_archiever\\app\\mai n.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Mohamad\\PycharmProjects\\offline_file_archiever\\build'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=None,
             hiddenimports=['sqlite3'],
             runtime_hooks=[],       
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)

    pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
                 cipher=block_cipher)
    exe = EXE(pyz,
              a.scripts,
              exclude_binaries=True,
              name='sample_build',
              debug=False,
              strip=False,
              upx=True,
              console=True )



    coll =     COLLECT(exe,Tree('C:/Users/Mohamad/PycharmProjects/offline_file_archiever/app/gui'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in glew.dep_bins],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='sample_build')
```

However the application is just launching and closing instantly, i couldn't find the problem

Comment: Run the app from the command line. This will show you the errors. Most likely you are missing some file that you need to include in `hiddenimports`.

Comment: What shall i add in the hiddenimports ?

Comment: @MohamadAlhaddad look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15318447/5994041)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that i didn't add "sqlite3" which is included in the models package, i think it couldnt appear for the analyse as well as i have added the .kv file as datas because it was marked None

datas=None ---> datas = [('/package/file.something','destination folder after compilation')]